# Encoding Android Camera Frames h263/h264

Tags: android, c, ffmpeg, h.264, x264

I want to implement a Video Chatting app on **Android** . I created a **SurfaceView** , get Camera preview and captured the frame as a **byte[ ]** using **Camera.PreviewCallback.onPreviewFrame( )** method . Now I want to encode that byte[ ] to a **h263** frame , pass over the network . Also get similar type of frame over network , decode it to a byte[ ] ( or a displayable format ) , and show it in a View . I want to do it **at least 15 FPS** rate . I am asking help for the **encoding/decoding** part .

For that purpose , which library would be suitable for me ? From where I should start ? Is my starting point wrong ? Is there any support on **SDK** or would I have to use **NDK** ? I have heard about **FFMpeg/x264** library , but I could not figure out how I can use them in my purpose . It's highly appreciated If you name **any library , any reference , learning path , link** or **code snippet** . Can you help me saying any **workflow** I should follow ? What if I want to use **h264 encoding** ? I just want to get it done , **GPL/LGPL license of library would not matter a lot** .

I am a beginner in Android development . **Any kind of assistance would be highly appreciated . Thanks in advance .**

Comment: Is H264 codec a requirement? Google has royalty-free VP8 encoder which is easy to use on Android.

Answer (score 0):

Use VLC's x264 for that,it would be a better option.....

Answer (score 0):

You can try [javacv](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv), which is a wrapper for `ffmpeg`, and there is also an example [RecordActivity](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/blob/master/samples/RecordActivity.java) to refer.